# Display a graph as shown in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I need to display a graph as shown below in python.

It basically displays how far is the person in front of the device. Say if the person is 0.6m away from the device, it should highlight the 6th region as shown in the chart.

[image]

Comment: Does your device have a means of determining Depth?  Because without 2 cameras, you cant tell how far you are from a device.

Comment: device is not a camera. its a radar. I do have the distance but the distance has to be visualized as shown above

Comment: without a sense of understanding land features, etc... visualizing distance instead of a number doesnt really mean much.  If it also visualized a rock for example, you could see the map/chart and then see that it is approximately the distance of the rock (or other) away.

Comment: am just developing the GUI using python and I need a way to do this. I don't know what kind of graph chart should be used to do this. Any documentation or example on how to do this would really help.

Comment: I think a polar bar plot would be a good start, you might be able to adapt this code: http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/polar_bar.html

Comment: I think the type of graph chart you are looking for is a radar chart. There is some documentation on the radar chart type here, with examples and explanation on how to put the chart together: https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/radar-charts/